# Count over different tables

Tags: sql, count, blacklist

I want to make a blacklist for my system. When someone **cancelled 3 times** he must be blacklisted. So a `reservation` has a `booker_id` so I have to count all this booker id's with the status canceled. The status canceled is in the other column `reservation_status`.

Can someone help me with this query please?  I have something like this but don't know if it is in the good way

```
select count(case 
        when reservation_status = 'Canceled' then 1 
        else null end) as booker_id
```

Comment: What does the schema look like? is there a separate blacklist table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select booker_id, count(reservation_status)
from YourTable
where reservation_status = 'Canceled'
group by booker_id
having count(reservation_status) >= 3
```